# Red5 demos don't work

Tags: installation, centos, red5

I just installed red5 on my server, and the install seems to work fine.  As you can see here: http://onelifemedia.com:5080

I got this far by using this walkthrough: http://www.webhostingtalk.com/showthread.php?t=1046590

The /demos page gives me a 404 error.  So I logged onto the server, and checked to see if the "demo" directory was already there.  It was not.

The applications that I installed were a directory up from the root directory.  I'm not sure if this is right or not.

Either way, my end goal is to actually get something working besides the main page.  If I can get the demos to work, then hopefully I should be well on my way.

I guess my questions can be broken down like this:
Does anyone know how to get the demos working?
Should I forget about the demos, and try to start writing my own code?
If I should write my own code, how should I go about installing it?  Since the installer is not properly installing the demos.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The tutorial is good but you dont need the admin app. Use the installer link in the tutorial and install the demo you want to use. The content of the "demos" directory is only the swf files used to access the server demos which you use the installer app to install. For instance , select "oflaDemo" and then from the main page navigate to demos/oflaDemo et voila.

I know I'm biased being a core developer, but we've attempted to make the server as ez as possible to use.

Comment: not all the demos are listed in installer page, how to install others besides only three listed there?

Answer (score 0):

I could install demos  from the latest svn trunk, Checkout the source, use ant&ivy to build and run the server and you can install two sample apps(oflaDemo and SOSample).
You may need to use ivy commands resolve some of the common issues during installations.

E:\dev\red5\java\server\trunk>ant ivyclear dist

(*)Red5 user mailing list may help you, because this is not exactly problem with Red5 source.
(*)http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11156222/red5-demos-not-working/11935532#11935532

I could resolve the issue based on the information in Red5 users mailing list and comments by Mr.Mondain in one of the posts in Stackoverflow