# Red5 demos not working

Tags: red5

*I have checked the similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10819597/red5-demos-dont-work) but that doesn't solve my problem.*

I have recently installed Red5 1.0 RC3 version for Windows/Java 7 successfully. But I am unable to install the demos. It returns the following debug messages:

```
Host: localhost
Trying to connect
Net status: NetConnection.Connect.Success
Got the server java version: 1.6
Got the application list
Async Error: [AsyncErrorEvent type="asyncError" bubbles=false cancelable=false eventPhase=2 text="Error #2095" error=ArgumentError: Error #1063]
Got an alert: Application oflaDemo was not installed
```

Following is the list of my environment vars :

```
declare -x ANT_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\WinAnt"
declare -x CLASSPATH=".;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jre7\\lib\\ext\\QTJava.zip.;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_04\\lib;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_04\\lib\\tools.jar;C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_04\\lib\\dt.jar"
declare -x JAVA_HOME="C:\\Program Files\\Java\\jdk1.7.0_04"
declare -x PATH="/c/Users/anks/bin:.:/usr/local/bin:/mingw/bin:/bin:/c/WINDOWS/system32:/c/WINDOWS:/c/WINDOWS/System32/Wbem:/c/WINDOWS/System32/WindowsPowerShell/v1.0/:/c/Program Files/QuickTime/QTSystem/:/c/MinGW/bin:/c/Python27:/c/Python27/Scripts:/c/Program Files/Java/jdk1.7.0_04/bin:/c/Program Files/WinAnt/bin:/c/Program Files/Mint/bin"
```

It lists the Java version 6, but I have 7 installed. Do I need to install Java 6 for the demos to work ?

Or is it an issue with the file permissions on Windows ? I tried to give full control to the Red5/webapps directory from the properties dialog to the current user, but that did not help.

Answer (score 3):

Turns out that the demos do not work with Java 7 for me. Downgraded to Java 6 and Red5 0.9.1. Did a manual install for the demos from [here](http://red5.googlecode.com/svn/snapshots/) and it works now. (Somehow the installer did not work)

Comment: are you using latest red5 for eclipse plugin and able to start the server in red5 without getting Bean stack errors with red5 0.9.1 version?

Comment: I did not use red5 eclipse plugin. Ran it from the command line without any errors.

Comment: Update your red5 to a newer version, the fixes are there 1.0.3 or newer.

Answer (score 1):

I have experienced that the two samples get installed with latest Red5 1.0, windows env, java1.7.x (java 1.7.0_5 is my java version).

If you use windows installer you need to add registry entry that was missing with latest red5 and java 7

If you build and run the server from the latest svn trunk, use ant&ivy to build and run the server and you can install two sample apps(oflaDemo and SOSample).

I do noI have experienced that the two samples get installed with latest Red5 1.0, windows env, java1.7.x (java 1.7.0_5 is my java version).

If you use windows installer you need to add registry entry that was missing with latest red5 and java 7.

env: windows, java7

D:\Red5Trunk\server>javac -version
javac 1.7.0_05

D:\Red5Trunk\server>java -version
java version "1.7.0_05"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_05-b06)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.1-b03, mixed mode, sharing)

D:\Red5Trunk\server

D:\Red5Trunk\server>ant ivyclear dist  (this command will be useful if your build fails even after having proper env and latest source from trunk)
D:\Red5Trunk\server>ant server

Answer (score 0):

The java6 notation is a "minimum" version, they will work with java7. I have recently fixed some of the previous installer issues with the newer version check.

Answer (score 0):

Red5 efficiently works with Java 1.6 version for 64-bit machine.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, it have been a while but I would like to add that if your are under Windows 7 or 8 you need to start the red5 service as an administrator user, otherwise windows will restrict some capabilities and it will be hell. Sometimes is really difficult to realise what is happening.

Regards from Cuba